# Connecting two columns in MS Excel

Tags: excel, relationship, multiple-columns

I have two columns called Primary Source and Secondary Source in MS Excel. I was wondering if there is anyway I could connect these 2 columns with each other i.e, if I select something from Primary Source, the corresponding value or the various options under that head must be shown in Secondary Source.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

You provide very little information about your spreadsheet. I think you are after dependent data validation, where the first cell offers a choice of, say "Continent" and you can select "America", "Africa", "Asia", "Europe", etc. and after you have made a selection, the next cell will present a choice of countries in the selected continent.

If that is what you want to do, take a look at dependent data validation at Debra Dalgleish's site here:
http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html

It involves setting up named ranges for the different options and using Indirect() to create the source for the secondary validation list.